# How to insert an element into a HTML input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, google-chrome-extension

I have to develop a script (extension content script) that will be inject in any page that contains a form.

In that page, the script has to insert into some input field, aligned to right, a clickable element (button for example).

The html page:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="input-field">
</div>
```

The script:

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.textContent = "?";

var inpuntField = document.querySelector("#input-field");

// Here I have to insert the button into the input field
```

The result must be like this:

```
-------------------
|               ? |
-------------------
```

I found a lot of solutions for this, but all of them need to edit the style attribute of the input element or the input's parent,
and I don't want to edit the original page, to prevent any problem with the page's view.

Does anyone know how to do this or can suggest a solution? Grateful.

Comment: No, you cannot put a button inside an input element. You can put an input element inside of a div along with a button, and make the div look like an input with a button in it.

Comment: [An `<input>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element) has no content.  (It doesn't even have a closing tag, so there's nowhere to *put* content.)  You can't put other elements *inside* of it, but (as you've already indicated) you can put other elements alongside it in the DOM and style them to *appear* "inside" of it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this. A `<label>` is technically an element. You can make pretty much anything clickable in HTML.

```js
let label = document.createElement("label");
let labelText = document.createTextNode("?");
label.appendChild(labelText);

document.querySelector("input").after(label);
label.addEventListener("click", function(){
 alert("clicked");
});
```

```css
label {
outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type=text></input>
</div>
```